# how to query list of data on firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list. I need to check with field on firestore.

```
 var ref = _db.collection('requirement')
        .where('subCategory.id',arrayContains: ['8ZaGrU1kMGqxnYWBGO5R','UHtbfwoHOtdZ1rwlpjFE']);
```

this way is not working.

Comment: is it like `where id in array` ?

Comment: yes, Is it possible to do with firestore?

Comment: possible with IN queries but i think the update will come late to flutter.https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html?linkId=76644965

Comment: @suhaibsalem That is actually the correct answer to this question at the moment, so would you mind posting it as an answer. That way BloodLoss can accept it, and I can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible with IN queries but i think the update will come late to flutter https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html?linkId=76644965

**Updated:**

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-

0.12.11 #
Added support for in and array-contains-any query operators.

Comment: `in` is not yet support on flutter.